# My domain broke somehow

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns, domain

Greetings and nice to meet you all.

I have a networking issue that I can't seem to overcome. Please be gentle as my networking foo is poor and I am new here.  Some specifics:

---

My web server. I'm hosting a domain simply to provide access to my files via dokuwiki and owncloud. I set this up a couple of years ago and it has worked fine, until it simply stopped last week. In my efforts to get it back up and running, I reinstalled the web server and my desktop. I have very good backups, but of course restoring backups hasn't solved anything.

The server:
Linux 4.4.74-desktop-1.mga5 #1 SMP Mon Jun 26 07:50:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)

OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

Internet connection is fiber from my ISP (Yucca.net, formerly Plateautel.net) through a Buffalo Airstation WXR-1900DHP (Version 2.37)

Ports 80 and 443 are forwarded from the internet side of my router to the internal ip of my webserver

My domain registrar is namecheap.com.

The domain is: adams-lan.org

---

When this thing was working I could access my web server from inside the LAN simply by pointing my desktop's browser to https: //adams-lan.org/ dokuwiki, for example.

Now, pointing a browser to https: //adams-lan.org/  takes me to my router config page. Pointing my browser to https: //23.252.218.244 also takes me to the router's config page.  It didn't used to do that.

Ports are open according to nmap:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8000/tcp open  http-alt
```

As near as I can tell, packets are moving from my ISP to my server and slamming against my router. I don't know why.

nslookup shows me the domain:

```
    nslookup adams-lan.org
Server:         208.67.222.222
Address:        208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   adams-lan.org
Address: 23.252.218.244
```

nslookup does not work in the other direction

```
nslookup 23.252.218.244
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 208.67.222.222, trying next server
Server:         208.67.220.220
Address:        208.67.220.220#53

** server can't find 244.218.252.23.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL
```

Does my isp need a PTR record?

Pinging hostname stalls, but does eventually respond.
Pinging IP kicks right off, responds nicely.

iptables are down

```
iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     base-address.mcast.net/24
```

The ip is not static and it's being tracked by ddclient.

What am I missing?

I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Note: internal links are intentionally broken because I don't have enough cred yet.

Comment: You should update your OpenSSL it's outdated

Comment: Have you cjeck that you internal server still ha the same IP address and if not that your router is forwarding to the new address?

Comment: The server box is configured with a static IP and it was solid the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your router is not configured to forward packets to your computer.  Routers generally have a couple of ways of doing it (and call the same thing by various names).   The solutions need to be programmed in your router.

The more appropriate solution is to map specific ports to IP addresses on your LAN.  This is often called "Port Forwarding" or "Pinholing", and is the more secure option.

An alternative is to set up a "DMZ" and forward all incoming traffic without an associated outbound port to a specific IP - the IP address of your server.  This does, however, mean your server is more exposed to the Internet then it need be.

(If you are landing on the router page when you enter an IP address, its not a DNS problem.  Similarly the issues with "Reverse DNS" are really irrelevant to your problem)

Comment: The SSL is provided by my distro. I'm sticking with it until the packager upgrades it. But thanks for noticing. As for the router, trouble seems to be that it *was* configured to forward ports. I turned those foreword rules off tonight and it magically resolved the issue. Had to turn them off for ports 443 and 80 as well as my ports for ssh and ftp. Once they were disabled, packets flew with no trouble. I have no idea how that works.